# Moving App to SD Card in Android 10 (LineageOS 17.1)

Tags: applications, sd-card, storage, lineageos, android-10

My phone (a Samsung A3 2016) used to allow me to move some apps to the SD card under its stock ROM (Android 7).

Last year I updated to Android 9 using LineageOS 16.0 and more recently to Android 10 with LineageOS 17.1.

However, ever since I made the switch I've lost the ability to move apps to the SD card. I go into Settings>Apps and notifications>App Info, choose an app that I know can be transferred, and the option is no longer there. I was hoping that the upgrade to Android 10 would fix this but it hasn't.

Does Android 10 no longer support this feature? Is it just the custom ROM I've used? Or is there a way to re-enable this feature. I would really like to get it working again as my phone only has 16GB of internal storage.

Comment: you mean [adoptable-storage](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/adoptable-storage/info) is not working?

Comment: @alecxs no, that option is there for me. Under Android 7 I could use the SD card as portable storage whilst also being able to move some apps over to there. Is that just no longer a thing?

Comment: i have android 7 tell me name of example app to move i will test

Comment: @alecxs I remember Instagram and VLC being capable of doing it. Maybe it was just a Samsung ROM only thing.

Comment: not working on android 7. maybe you mean android 5 (old Samsung devices)

Comment: @alecxs It was definitely running Android 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out; reformatting the SD card as internal storage activates this feature.

I can now move some apps to the SD card rather than the phone's internal storage.