# How to move Apps to the adoptable sd-card storage on LineageOS 17.1 (Samsung Galaxy S5 klte)?

Tags: sd-card, lineageos, android-10, internal-sd, adoptable-storage

Hi since I updated to LineageOs 17.1 I am having storage problems, because the management of the adoptable storage does not work as expected.

**The problem:**
LineageOs migrates constantly data from the sd-card (used as internal storage) to the real internal storage. Somehow the play, and apps like WhatsApp distinct between the internal storage and the adoptable storage and ask me to free space. WhatsApp even stopps working. So I constantly remove apps, but even freeing several GB of data does not help because LineageOs moves more and more data to the internal storage.

**What I did to cause the problem:**

- Installed LineageOs 17.1 and enabled adb debugging.
- Deleted the old partition table of my sd-card
- used adb shell to format the sd-card with: sm partition disk:179,64 private
- put a lot of data to my phone
- **by accident clicked** in the options of the internal storage on "**migrate data**", what is the opposite of what I want. The process terminated with an error because of running out of storage. So maybe it never stopped and some flag is still set somewhere, what causes my problem?

**What I tried to solve the problem:**

- Rooted the phone with Magisk
- Installed app2sd pro from Bicky Bonick and tried to move apps. This did not help because the app seems to be targeted to an environment with a portable and non-adoptable sd-card storage? Clicking on linking apps to the sdcard results in an at this stage not further specified error. I just think this is the wrong way to go?

**The question:**

How can I increase the 16GB internal space available (with LineageOs 17.1) for apps on my phone by using my external 64GB sd-card?

This question might be related to [this one](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/225562/87660).

Comment: please explain *"migrate data is the opposite of what I want"*

Comment: I think this means that data is moved from the sd-card to the phones internal stoarge

Comment: *"migrate data*" is the 2nd necessary step after 1st step *"adoptable-storage*" is created. it will move all apps from phone into sdcard (if app is moveable). all new installed apps will directly installed into sdcard. if you don't want to migrate, just uninstall+reinstall some of your apps

Comment: Sure I did this after setting up the adoptable-storage. But after this was done "migrate data" was just clickable on the internal storage (on LineageOS 17.1) and the phone never stopped to move data from the sd-card to the phone storage.

People in #lineageos @irc.freenode.net told me that using adoptable storage in general is a bad idea, but how in this case work with the Samsung Galaxy S5? I will always have storage issues with the 16GB internal memory. This is so little.

Comment: what you see as "internal storage" is the (adopted) MicroSD Card in real. "migrate data" won't transfer apps from sd-card to phone, it will (try to) move apps from phone to (adopted) internal storage (depending on [android:installLocation](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/43517)). when 100% disk space adopted you can't see your MicroSD Card any longer, the only way to check disk usage is from cmd line [df -h /mnt/expand/\*](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/220729) (if your device is rooted consider 3rd party apps like Link2SD instead)

Comment: LineageOs showed both storages separately, despite I formatted the sd-card as 100 % adopted (as described above)

Comment: maybe lineageos is bit smarter? anyway, check the output of `df -h`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with lineage 15.1 on my samsung s4mini.
the solution which worked....

- under 15.1 I formatted the sd as internal storage
- I copied all relevant system zip files to the sd card (lineage 15.1 / open gapps 8.1 pico / supersu v82)
- I booted to twrp recovery and wiped everything except preload and the sd card
- then I installed all above mentioned 3 relevant system files from the sd-card in one go
- I rebooted and my sd card was still configured as internal memory and newly installed apps moved to a large extent to the sd card and the phone was still rooted - it was perfect

having installed apps which would not have fitted to internal memory before I am now using only 3.3 of 8.0  gb and if I install more apps the real internal memory will fill up just slowly....

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to revive this year old thread but found a method which seems to solve this issue so just want to put it down here for everyone's benefit. I am on LineageOS 18.1 (Android 11):

1. Enable Developer Options (Settings -> About -> Tap build number 7
   times)
2. In Developer Options under Apps section there is a setting called
   Force allow apps on external, enable that.
3. Now you should be able to go to Settings -> Apps and click on each
   app to see if they are using Internal Storage or SD card, if it is
   on Internal Storage you can move it to SD card.

Using this method most of my apps could be moved to SD card. One thing I noticed is the space used doesn't really update immediately and I had to reboot the device to see the space used in internal storage.